# Vue, cloning div on click but having unique input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've successfully set up this page where I dynamically add a div/row of inputs, and this works (click the link and it adds the same div below the current one with all proper inputs)

Also, one of the inputs is setup as an autosuggest/autocomplete search box. This works perfectly as well as when I type it searches and returns my results (If i click a result it replaces the text in that input)

So, the two main factors here are working perfectly. But I have an issue: If I add one or more of the divs, the input in each one reflects the same text. Meaning, if I type 'Test' into the third row's input it will show in that same input for every div/row.

How can I fix this so that each added div's input has it's own text but they all get added to my same v-model array?

```js
<script>
new Vue({
  components: {},
  el: "#commonNameDiv",
  data() {
    return {
      searchString: [' '],
      results: [],
      savedAttributes: [],
      cards: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    autoComplete() {
      this.results = [];
      console.log(this.searchString);
      if (this.searchString.length > 2) {
        this.results = [
          {attribute_value:"apple"},
          {attribute_value:"banane"}
        ]
      }
    },
    saveAttribute(result) {
      this.savedAttributes = [];
      console.log('cool');
      this.savedAttributes.push(result.attribute_value);
      console.log('here is the attribute');
      console.log(this.savedAttributes);
      this.searchString = result.attribute_value;
      this.results = [];
    },
    addCard: function() {
      this.cards.push({
        index: ''
      })
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js" </script>

<div id="commonNameDiv">
  <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
      <input size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-6-10">
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" v-model="searchString[index]" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
      <div class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="results.length">
         <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results"><a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result)">{{ result.attribute_value }}</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-2-10" style="border: 1px solid black; height:50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto;" >

     </div>
  </div>

  <div v-for="(card,index) in cards" class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
      <input size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-6-10">
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" v-model="searchString[index]" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
      <div class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="results.length">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
            <a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result)">@{{ result.attribute_value}  </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-2-10" style="border: 1px solid black; height:50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="height: 35px;">

  </div>

  <div>
    <a v-on:click="addCard">Add another zone</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  components: {},
  el: "#commonNameDiv",
  data() {
    return {
      searchString: [''],
      results: [],
      savedAttributes: [],
      cards: ['']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    autoComplete(index) {
      this.results = [];
      console.log(this.searchString[index]);
      if (this.searchString[index].length > 2) {
        this.results = [{
            attribute_value: "apple"
          },
          {
            attribute_value: "banane"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    saveAttribute(result) {
      this.savedAttributes = [];
      console.log('cool');
      this.savedAttributes.push(result.attribute_value);
      console.log('here is the attribute');
      console.log(this.savedAttributes);
      this.searchString = result.attribute_value;
      this.results = [];
    },
    addCard: function() {
      this.cards.push({
        index: ''
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="commonNameDiv">
  <div v-for="(card,index) in cards" class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
      <input size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-6-10">
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" v-model="searchString[index]" v-on:keyup="autoComplete(index)" class="form-control">
      <div class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="results.length">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
            <a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result)">@{{ result.attribute_value }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-2-10" style="border: 1px solid black; height:50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="height: 35px;">

  </div>

  <div>
    <a v-on:click="addCard">Add another zone</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I see the change you made but it still glitches on the input and doesn't allow for selection at all now

Comment: If I select Apple, it puts 'A' in the first input and 'P' in the second input

Comment: it'll be best if  you make a component of this.It will work independently

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having this issue is that your cards are bound (via v-model) to the single data property `searchString`. In order for solve this issue, they need to be bound to individual properties.

The solution is to add a new property to each object in your `cards` array. You can do that in the `addCard` method. Something like:

```js
addCard: function () {
  this.cards.push({searchString: ''}) // here, each card has its own searchString value
}
```

And then in your template, you would have

```js
<div v-for="(card,index) in cards" class="uk-grid">
...
  <div class="uk-width-6-10">
    <input ... v-model="card.searchString"> // bind the value to each card's individual searchString property
...
<div>
    <a v-on:click="addCard">Add another zone</a>
</div>
...
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems to work in the cloned element with the input having it's own search but it still affects the results, so when I search in any input the dropdown for all dev elements populates

Answer (score 1):

Define `searchString` as an array and use the **v-model** as `v-model="searchString[index]"`. Here is the working code.

```js
new Vue({
  components: {},
  el: "#commonNameDiv",
  data() {
    return {
      searchString: [' '],
      results: [],
      savedAttributes: [],
      cards: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    autoComplete() {
      this.results = [];
      console.log(this.searchString);
      if (this.searchString.length > 2) {
        axios.get('/product/parts/components/search', {
          params: {
            searchString: this.searchString
          }
        }).then(response => {
          this.results = response.data;
          console.log(this.results);
          console.log(this.searchString);
        });
      }
    },
    saveAttribute(result) {
      this.savedAttributes = [];
      console.log('cool');
      this.savedAttributes.push(result.attribute_value);
      console.log('here is the attribute');
      console.log(this.savedAttributes);
      this.searchString = result.attribute_value;
      this.results = [];
    },
    addCard: function() {
      this.cards.push({
        index: ''
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='commonNameDiv'>
  <div v-for="(card,index) in cards" class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
      <input size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-6-10">
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" v-model="searchString[index]" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
      <div class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="results.length">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
            <a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result)">@{{ result.attribute_value }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-2-10" style="border: 1px solid black; height:50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a v-on:click="addCard">Add another zone</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it does work in these terms but my autocomplete function now throws the error "Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render" which fails before the axios call

Comment: it can be solved easily by define `searchString: [ '' ]` in data. I hope it work

Comment: Can you check the snippet I added to my question above? I got past it but it still uses the first letter of my iitial input search to populate the next input and then it affects both dropdowns. It's just acting a bit glitchy

Comment: you use seachString in 2 places with index and without index. So problem occurs

Comment: well I had it on both and ran into that first issue, but now I have it on both and set searchString the way you said but it give me the issue of index veing undefined again

Comment: you want a card default .. right?? so you copied the same code

Comment: Yes the page should load with the first div outside of the v-if, then after that it should duplicate the html and give each its own results and search string

Comment: index is only define into the v-for. I add another answer of an default card